# How to multiply 2 values from different tables in Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datalist

I try to multiply 2 values from different table but it's keep error like this:

[image: Imgur]

Here's my code:

```
    //Label12 is in datalist
    var Label12 = (Label)(((Button)sender).Parent).FindControl("Label12");  

    var item2 = from c in db.OrderTemps
                join o in db.Products
                on c.Prod_ID equals o.Prod_ID
                select new
                {
                   o.Prod_ID,
                   o.Prod_Price, //Type "Decimal"
                   c.Amount, //Type "Integer"
                   c.Total, //Type "Decimal
                   s = o.Prod_Price * c.Amount
                };

     foreach (var i in item2)
     {
        Label12.Text = Convert.ToString(i.s); //an error happen here!!
     }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with you LINQ query. If no records joined, then there will be nothing to enumerate and you will skip foreach body. I think you have `Label12` equal to `null`. Check if it really exist on senders parent.

SIDE NOTE: Why are you trying to assign text in loop? Label will keep only last value assigned.

Comment: Excuse me. How can I check that.

Comment: @OliverCatipon set breakpoint before foreach and check value of `Label12` variable. If it will be `null` (and I'm sure it will be) then you should check which control sent this event, check what value has Parent of this control, and then go to UI and verify if parent has such label

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your amount value in **OrderTemps** table is null. or Check whether you really have a controller which has the ID = Label12. 
Nothing wrong in your Linq query...